# Django add same class attribute to all same type fields

Tags: django, attributes

Is there any easy way to assign `class=radio` to all elements whose widget is radioselect in a form ?
I know I can write such that

```
rb = forms.ChoiceField( widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs='class':'radio'))
```

for all radio buttons in the form but I think there should be other ways. Because I probably use it for all radio buttons and it is not funny to write this for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own widget, like this:

```
class MyRadioSelect(forms.RadioSelect):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         attrs = kwargs.pop("attrs", {})
         if "class" in attrs:
             attrs["class"] = "%s radio" % attrs["class"]
         else:
             attrs["class"] = "radio"
         kwargs["attrs"] = attrs
         super(MyRadioSelect, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

like this?

```
class ClassyRadioSelect(forms.RadioSelect):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #yes, i've to look up how to process args and kwargs properly
        attrs = kwargs.get('attrs', {})
        attrs['class'] = ' '.join((attrs.get('class',''), 'radio'))
        kwargs['attrs'] = attrs
        super(ClassyRadioSelect, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class ClassyChoiceField(forms.ChoiceField):
    def __init__(self, choices=(), required=True, widget=None, label=None,
                 initial=None, help_text=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if not widget:
            widget = ClassyRadioSelect()
        super(ClassyChoiceField, self).__init__(choices, required, widget, label
                                                , initial, help_text, *args,
                                                **kwargs)

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    classy_field1 = ClassyChoiceField()
    classy_field2 = ClassyChoiceField()
```